# How to Integrate Radar Overlay for displaying weather?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, radar-chart

I am new in iOS development.In one of my project i have to develop radar display for weather.i don't have any idea on that.I want something like this http://www.weather.com/maps/maptype/currentweatherusnational/usdopplerradar_large.html please check it i am not able to show image here.

My Requirement is something like this.Can anyone please help me on this task.can me any suggestion or guide me what should i do for this.I am new in iOS development.

Comment: Please Refer the answers of this Question it may Help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568861/how-can-i-integrate-radar-overlay-on-mapview/9892793#9892793

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with the [MapKit Framework documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008210). You will need to create an MKMapView for your map, then an MKOverlayView for your overlay view, and some object of yours will need to implement the MKOverlay protocol. You will add that baby to your map view using

```
-[MapView addOverlay:]
```

Best place to start is the docs. Overlay examples can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html). If you don't understand the concept of objects and delegates, you will need to start [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163).

Comment: is there any API is available which give's me radar included map.